# unable to render partial view in asp.net mvc using ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Problem is : I do have **Index.cshtml** as

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>Answer's are </h2>

<div id="result">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search Wiki",
                  "WikiAns",
                new AjaxOptions{
                    UpdateTargetId = "result",
                InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod="GET",
                LoadingElementId="progress"
                })

</div>
<div id="progress" style="display: none">
<img src="@Url.Content("../../Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif")" alt="loader" />
</div>
```

Now i do have partial view model **_WikiAns**:

```
@model IEnumerable<Questions.Models.WikiAnsClass>

    <h2>Our Links</h2>
    <table>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="@item.url" target="_blank">@item.content</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Now using above i want is that...on clicking **Search Wiki** action link, id="result" get all partial view rendered in it. But its not happening. Instead of its going to a page "`localhost:80/Search/WikiAns`" and showing the result there. but i want to it to stay at `localhost:80/Search` and replace its "result" id. but its not working this way.

Here is my action called `WikiAns`

```
public ActionResult WikiAns()
{
 //Code to follow...
 var wikians = //code to follow
  return PartialView("_wikiAns", wikians); 
 }
```

What's the problem ?

Also how can i implement this Ajax GIF loader...i mean showing it while action gets executed. ?

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors? Are you sure all the required .js files are loaded?

Comment: @Pbirkoff No javascript error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pbirkoff may be right about this but you can go through my post of very easy to implement demo of your scenario  and build it up from there.

http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2011/05/aspnet-mvc-razor-render-partial-view.html

http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-mvc-render-partial-view-using.html

Comment: added microsoft ajax scripts... its not working... [Updated the question]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include Microsoft Ajax scripts at your page or layout.

Comment: added microsoft ajax scripts... its not working... [Updated the question]